HTML input element capture="environment" getting the same image on iPad 9
I have 36 items that can be added photos directly using tablet. And I am using this kinda component  to handle images.
When i use this code on iPad 9 it is getting the first image that taken by the iPad camera. Is capture property of input tag is not implemented yet on iOS devices? I think this problem is not relative to the codebase. It is relative to the system.
const ImgUploadComponent = ({image_name,}) => {
  const showValidationMessage = (name: keyof I_INITIAL_OPTION_VALUES) =>
    touch[name] && errors[name] ? errors[name] : "";
  const addImage: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = async (e) => {
    if (e.target.files) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      const { name } = e.target;

      try {
        await CarController.getSingleLinkFromServer(file, (photo) => {
          setFieldValue(name, photo.url);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } finally {
        // Clear the file input value
        e.target.value = "";
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <input
      key={Math.random()}
      type="file"
      id={image_name}
      name={image_name}
      onChange={addImage}
      accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg, .webp"
      capture="environment"
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        opacity: 0,
        cursor: "pointer",
      }}
    />
  )
}

I tried this code.
